# CSS -> Having trouble with a very basic CSS layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to CSS/Javascript and am having trouble with something that seems like it should be simple.  I have a series of radio buttons and corresponding text.  I'd like it all to appear as a bullet-point list, but for some reason messing with the properties of one messes up (or supersedes?) the alignment of the other.

Trying to achieve this (text adjacent to button):

[image]

How do I style this in CSS?

```
<form id="form1">​
   <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"0" id=​"choice0">​
   <div id=​"c0" class=​"choiceText">​text here</div>​
   <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"1" id=​"choice1">​
   <div id=​"c1" class=​"choiceText">​text here</div>​
   <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"2" id=​"choice2">​
   <div id=​"c2" class=​"choiceText">​text here</div>​
</form>​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that the `div` element, by default, have its `display` CSS property set to `block`.

Quoting W3Schools, 'a block element is an element that takes up the full width available, and has a line break before and after it.' you may notice that both `<div>` and `<p>` behave like this.

You have a couple options here. You may want to use an element that have its `display` property already set to `inline` by default, like `span` or `label`. An inline element only takes up as much width as necessary, and does not force line breaks.

You may also set your `DIV`s to `display:inline` instead of the standard `display:block`. But then you'll probably want to break the line after the content; in that case you can use the `:after` selector marker, adding a line break - like this:

```
<style>
    div.choicetext { display:inline; }
    div.choicetext:after { content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }
</style>

<form id="form1">​
   <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"0" id=​"choice0">​
   <div id=​"c0" class=​"choiceText">​text here</div>​
   <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"1" id=​"choice1">​
   <div id=​"c1" class=​"choiceText">​text here</div>​
   <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"2" id=​"choice2">​
   <div id=​"c2" class=​"choiceText">​text here</div>​
</form>​
```

Comment: Aren't you making this slightly complex? What you're doing is achieved by the `label` tag.

Comment: I don't think so, @pattmorter. The OP explicitly mentioned his interest in learning how to do it via CSS - his question is 'How do I style this in CSS?'. A suggestion to use a label tag doesn't explain why he's getting that result; the extra information is intended to show him why it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, use the `<label>` tag. Doesn't require extra styling or any CSS tricks to make it work. It just works. Thats what the `<label>` tag was created for.

Here's the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wK639/)

```
<form id="form1">
   <input type="radio" name="choices" class="radioButtons" value="0" id="choice0">
   <label id="c0" class="choiceText">text here</label>
   <input type="radio" name="choices" class="radioButtons" value="1" id="choice1">
   <label id="c1" class="choiceText">text here</label>
   <input type="radio" name="choices" class="radioButtons" value="2" id="choice2">
   <label id="c2" class="choiceText">text here</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <form id="form1">
      ​
      <div id=​"c0" class=​"choiceText">​
        <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"0" id=​"choice0">
        ​ text here</div>
      ​
      <div id=​"c1" class=​"choiceText">
        <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"1" id=​"choice1">
        ​ ​text here</div>
      ​
      <div id=​"c2" class=​"choiceText">
        <input type=​"radio" name=​"choices" class=​"radioButtons" value=​"2" id=​"choice2">
        ​ ​text here</div>
      ​
    </form>
```